# Reseting HTML5 canvas for signature

Tags: javascript

im using this script:
http://www.lisenme.com/e-signature-pad-using-jquery-ajax-php-digital-signature-pad-submission-form/

And im tryin to make button for reseting canvas, so if user makes mistake he can reset and sign again.

I was googleing around and tried few different ways but looks like this script has some own way for reseting canvas.

Problem is because im not so good with JS, so i couldnt' make it :(

can somebody help me with some example how i can make reset button?

Thanks

Comment: If you read the link you posted yourself, the first comment will answer your question.

Comment: @nitowa  yea but i dont know how to use provided code with button?

Answer (score 2):

You can Clear the Canvas of Signaturepad -

```
<div id="signArea" >
  <h2 class="tag-ingo">Put signature below,</h2>
  <div class="sig sigWrapper" style="height:auto;">
    <div class="typed"></div>
    <canvas class="sign-pad" id="sign-pad" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Now add the Clear Canvas click event -

```
// Create the Signaturepad
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#signArea').signaturePad({drawOnly:true, drawBezierCurves:true, lineTop:0});
});

// Clear the Signaturepad
$('#clear').click(function() {
  $('#signArea').signaturePad().clearCanvas();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the script you're running but if you can access the canvas context directly typically you should use the clearRect() function to clear the canvas.

const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Answer (score 0):

Author of script i mentioned above said in comments to some user:

> please use the code below
>
> “var signaturePad1 = new SignaturePad(sign1_canvas);
>   signaturePad1.clear();”

But i dont understand how to use this code with button?

Comment: i tried with:$("#reset").click(function(e){
                    var signaturePad1 = new SignaturePad(sign1_canvas);
                    signaturePad1.clear();
                  });

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ox = canvas.width / 2;
var oy = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.font = "42px serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "#800";
ctx.fillRect(ox / 2, oy / 2, ox, oy);

var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, { backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' });

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#bfirmar").on("click", function () {
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
        $("#FirmaBase64").val(canvas.toDataURL());
    });

    $("#blimpiar").on("click", function () {
        signaturePad.clear();
    });
});
```